# Div Hover Problem

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I've got 2 divs, **me** and **bubble** inside another div called **holder**. I want to fire an action when a user hovers over **holder**. For some reason when I hover over **me** the action works correctly, but when I hover over **bubble** it doesnt register as being over the **holder** div.

Here is the code.

```
$("#iholder").hoverIntent(function() {
    $("#me").css({
    "background-image": "url(img/me-hover.gif)",
    timeout: 50        
    });
$(this).css({
    "cursor": "pointer",     
    });
$("#bubble").animate({
    opacity: "show"     
    }, "300");
},
function() {
    $("#me").css({
    "background-image": "url(img/me.gif)",    
    }, "300");
$("#bubble").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "200");  
});
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="holder">
<div id="me"></div>
<div id="bubble"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add an answer with short details about what was actually wrong?  You can select it as the answer, and Victor will retain the rep he gained trying to help you.

Answer (score 2):

well to start, you got a typo here:

```
$("#holder").hoverIntent(function() {
    $("#me").css({
    "background-image": "url(img/me-hover.gif)",
    timeout: 50        
    });
```

you had `#iholder` instead of `#holder`

Comment: Ah, thats a mistake I made while posting here. Its not in my original code.